# Inline divs width issue

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get a layout like below and need to work with a html structure that cannot be modified.

[image]

The fiddle below works fine in non IE browsers but IE 9 and 10 are stretching 100% for each button.

I am using display:table and table-cell. I think the 100% width on each button is causing the issue but cannot find another solution that streches the buttons evenly, aligns the text and hovers properly.

I cannot change the html structure.

http://jsfiddle.net/9seuhjmt/

```
  .c-control-latch-buttons.tri-option-latch-buttons span.c-label {
      display: table-cell;
      width: 100%;
  }
```

I have a feeling i'm over complicating things so any tips much appreciated.

Comment: You have 100% width on the 'cell' should that not be the 'table row' and the cells be like 33%?

Comment: You sure everything is in the fiddle? It looks fine on my PC

Comment: Yes @CBauer, the issues are only in IE9 and 10

Comment: Yeah I was using IE developer console to look at it emulated for 9 + 10. What a useless feature if it doesn't even show up properly!

Answer (score 1):

is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/9seuhjmt/19/

it's behaving the same in my IE 9 and Chrome now.

I changed the table-cell to 1/3-ish of the area (34 to avoid a dark border when hoovering):

```
.c-control-latch-buttons.tri-option-latch-buttons span.c-label {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 34%;
```

IE wasn't accommodating all cells with 100% width. But when changing to 34% it was displaying the -moz-linear-gradient background colours (grey). The hover on IE was problematic due to the fallback background and found on the original css. I removed those and it's working here. If you can keep plain colours then removing these styles could be the solution.

[image: IE 9.0.8 printscreen]